# Is it possible for a Bash function, to output a value to a file descriptor, and assign only that to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stdin, file-descriptor

I wanted to simulate a return value for a Bash function, and I was wondering if it's possible to use an adhoc file descriptor, in order to pass the value.

In other words:

```sh
function myfunction {
  # print `stdout_value` to stdout
  # print `stderr_value` to stderr
  # print `return_value` to FD3 (or other)
}

# the values printed to stderr/stdout should be printed, but only
# `return_value` should be assigned to `myvalue`
myvalue=$(myfunction <FDs manipulation>)
```

Comment: Don't think of it as a return value.  Think of it as data written to FD3.  "Return value" already has a meaning, and trying to reuse the phrase for something different just confuses things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. But for that to work, first you need to save `stdout` to another descriptor for the whole call, and for command substitution; redirect file descriptor 3 to its `stdout`—so that what's written to it can be captured—, and its `stdout` to `stdout` of the whole call. E.g:

```
{ myvalue=$(myfunction 3>&1 1>&4); } 4>&1
```

Doing this for each call to that function sounds like a lot of work though. You better follow the convention that:

- use `stderr` for reporting errors, warnings and debug info (including logs and prompts),
- use `stdout` for showing results,
- and use a `return` statement to denote overall success/failure.

Answer (score 3):

Probably easiest to make a global copy of stdout first.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 4>&1
myfunction() {
        echo stdout
        echo stderr >&2
        echo fd3 >&3
} 3>&1 1>&4


v=$(myfunction)   # assigns the string "fd3"
echo v="$v"
```